# A class of "internal" endofunctors in cartesian closed categories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, type-theory

I'm interested in a class of endofunctors on cartesian closed categories with a quite natural definition, and am wondering whether/where this class has been studied so far (and how it is called).

Fix a cartesian closed category with exponential $\mathcal{C}(-,-)$. For any morphism $f : \mathbf{X} \to \mathbf{Y}$, let $\lambda_f : \mathbf{1} \to \mathcal{C}(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y})$ be the associated point.

Call an endofunctor $d$ "internal" (for lack of a better name), if for any two objects $\mathbf{X}$, $\mathbf{Y}$ there is a morphism $D : \mathcal{C}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y}) \to \mathcal{C}(d\mathbf{X}, d\mathbf{Y})$ such that for any morphism $f : \mathbf{X} \to \mathbf{Y}$ we find $\lambda_{df} = D \circ \lambda_f$.

Informally, the action of the endofunctor on the homsets is mirrored by the action of some morphism between the associated function spaces.

Have you encoutered this definition before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you also require the obvious compatibilities, you get an [enriched functor](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+functor).

Comment: If my understanding is correct, then any cartesian closed category may considered as enriched over itself, so the categories $C$, $D$, $V$ in that definition would all be the same category in my case. The "obvious compatibilities" would be the requirement that all the choices of morphism $D$ work together as expected, rather than restricting the endofunctor?